# How to copy file from local vagrant to local system?

Tags: linux, vagrant, scp

I want to copy `local.conf` from local vagrant machine to local system(my machine). Vagrant is running on the same machine.
I tried the following command. It run successfully, but when I search `local.conf` file on my system I get nothing.

```
[vagrant@localhost devstack]$ scp vagrant@192.168.50.4:/home/vagrant/local.conf local.conf 
vagrant@192.168.50.4's password: 
local.conf                                              100% 3857     3.8KB/s   00:00    
[vagrant@localhost devstack]$
```

Answer (score 5):

To copy files from host to vm (and vice versa) you do not necessarily need specific protocol like scope or ftp.

By default vagrant automatically makes a */vagrant* directory a shared folder with your local folder. so you can just copy any files from the vm into the */vagrant* directory and you will see them under your local folder where you have the Vagrantfile and where you initialized vagrant.

And if you have other files located on your local hard drive that you want to share with your vm, you can easily add a shared folder from the Vagrantfile

```
  config.vm.synced_folder "/Users/fhenri/myproject", "/project"
```

will shared the local folder */Users/fhenri/myproject* with the */project* folder from the vm and you can just use `mv` or `cp` to move / copy files from one to another

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify on which machine you run your command. Your command is basically correct, but you need to run it on your local host, not on vagrant machine. In example, you can think of two hosts, `local` and `vagrant`:

```
[local]$ scp vagrant@vagrant:/home/vagrant/local.conf local.conf 
vagrant@vagrant's password: 
local.conf                                      100% 3857     3.8KB/s   00:00
```

Trying `ls` in the same directory should show you your required file:

```
[local]$ ls local.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

for example:

"sudo scp -P 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/dumpfilename.sql /home/ "