# How to copy file from a Vagrant machine to localhost

Tags: linux, vagrant, scp

I want to copy a local file from a Vagrant machine to my `localhost`, but I am getting an error message:

> ssh: connect to host `127.0.0.1` port `22`: Connection refused.

```
[user@localhost ceil]$ scp -p 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/devstack/local.conf .
cp: cannot stat ‘2222’: No such file or directory
ssh: connect to host 127.0.0.1 port 22: Connection refused
```

I also tried using using `localhost` but still got the same error.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You should read the manual page for `scp`. The correct syntax is:

```
scp -P 2222 vagrant@127.0.0.1:/home/vagrant/devstack/local.conf .
```

The uppercase <kbd>P</kbd> is for "port". Lowercase is used to preserve modification times.

Comment: copy file to vagrant machine : 
scp -i .vagrant/machines/your_machine_name/virtualbox/private_key -P 2222 /path/file vagrant@127.0.0.1:

Answer (score 63):

Another option is `cat` the files to something local:

```
vagrant ssh -c "sudo cat /home/vagrant/devstack/local.conf" > local.conf
```

This should also work for files that require root permissions (something the vagrant SCP plugin doesn't seem to support).

Comment: This was a really handy workaround for trying to get files off a vagrant box somebody else set up.

Answer (score 33):

Get IdentityFile and Port by using

```
vagrant ssh-config
```

`scp -i IdentityFile_file -P Port vagrant@127.0.0.1:/file_dir dist_dir` e.g.

```
scp -i /Users/xxxxx/tmp/vagrant/centos_6.5/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key -P 2200  vagrant@127.0.0.1:/tmp/xxx .
```

Comment: Thanks! The command vagrant ssh-config is really handy.

Answer (score 11):

As @SevenJ mentioned, ssh-config can provide all the info you need. But it's a lot easier to save it to a file and use that file, rather than constructing a complicated scp command. E.g.:

```
vagrant ssh-config > config.txt
scp -F config.txt default:/path/to/file .
```

Here I'm assuming your vagrant file doesn't override the machine name from "default". If it does, replace "default:" with ":".

Comment: As of vagrant 2.0, you can control the host name with `vagrant ssh-config --host my-host`

Answer (score 9):

Another option like Dan linked to:

```
   vagrant plugin install vagrant-scp
   vagrant scp [vm_name]:<remote_path> <local_path
```

and if you need to do the opposite its

```
 vagrant scp <local_path> [vm_name]:<remote_path>
```

You can use `vagrant status` to get the name of the VM

```
Current machine states:

default                   running (virtualbox)
```

Where default is the name of the VM in my case.

Answer (score 5):

This is a handy tool for anyone coming in via Google: [Vagrant SCP](https://github.com/invernizzi/vagrant-scp)

Answer (score 0):

Additional tools like scp or cat may not be necessary. Frederick Henri covered it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32316105/2976571).

Essentially, `cp [file] /var/www/[your vm]/.vagrant` will  copy the file to the .vagrant folder at your project root, where you can see and move the file in your desktop OS.

Answer (score 0):

Oneliner:

```
scp -F =(cd $DIR_WITH_VAGRANTFILE && vagrant ssh-config) default:~/REMOTE_FILE .
```

It uses process substitution to create a temp file from `vagrant ssh-config` and uses that with the `-F` ssh/scp option.